# colmn_name UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL UNIQUE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, guid, uniqueidentifier, create-table

What is ROWGUIDCOL purpose here?

I tried googeling it and couldn't find anything that explains what ROWGUIDCOL does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a special marker which tells to a merge replication that this column should be used as a synchronisation key between publishers' and subscribers' versions of data.

Neither the column itself, nor the data in it are affected by this marker in any way. Think of it as a bit flag being set somewhere in the column metadata.

Comment: Okay, so why is it even in use?
I am trying to understand, when would I as a developer use ROWGUIDCOL. Any ideas?
P.S. thanks for answering that question. :)

Comment: @PaulKar. You might foresee the possibility that the database will participate in a merge replication and include such columns into tables from the start. Because if you don't, the Snapshot Agent will do it for you, and the database schema will become different from your development version, making schema compares more complex.